# How to ensure that the css border goes inside the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a some picture with border add with photoshop but these border are dirty.
I would overwrite these border without doing it with photoshop again (Can not use a script because almost every picture are too specifics), because my client gave me about 15000 pictures with this error..

Then, I though about css border.
So, how can I make the border around the image to fill the inside of it ?

Is it possible ? Have you a better idea ?

**EDIT**

List of ideas which don't work for my case:

1. css attribute : border-style: inset (thank you anyway Abdul Basit)
2. css attribute : clip

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `box-shadow` with `inset` to simulate a border. However the box-shadow does not work directly on the image element, because it will render behind.
You can solve this by making an `.image-wrapper` class with a `box-shadow` on.
And to make this shadow render in front of your image you just need to set the `z-index` to `-1`.

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.img-wrapper {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px red; // Fake border on the inside
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1; // Render the image behind the box-shadow
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2q8n5rao/)

Answer (score 3):

you can give inset border

```
   border-style: inset;
```

can add a width that covers approx of all borders

```
    border-width: 5px;
```

or you can use image as a border for all.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea, I tried it earlier but there is this beveling / stamping dirty effect with the border.
And it doesn't really fill the image as I wish..